# How does the acknowledgement callback function runs on client side in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

This is the emit Event written on the client-side.

```
socket.emit('test', 'This is a message', () => {
console.log('Callback Function');
});
```

This is the broadcaster written on the server-side.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
socket.on('test', (message, callback) => {
console.log(message);
callback();
})}
```

Whenever a 'test' event emits from client-side it gets executed on server-side. console.log(message) prints the message 'This is a message' on client-side (basically in express server logs), which is correct. But how does the callback function prints the message 'Callback Function' on browser console, while the callback was called on the server-side?

Comment: Are you asking for the specific implementation details? Socket.io will invoke the callback on the client-side once it is called by the server-side - see the [Acknowledgements](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emitting-events/#acknowledgements) section in the docs

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned express somewhere, this is gonna be easier for you to understand.
With express, when you send a request to a matched route, say get, you return a response, with your desired data.This is the request response lifecycle.

Not to get too technical,in socket io, a similar sequence of events happen under the hood:
when you perform a socket.emit event, in simple terms,

1. Request will be sent to your socket server.
2. Then, socket server will execute your logic
3. Once done, a kind of done event is raised.

If you passed the callbacks, which appears to be your case, this kind of done event am referring to, (3), will act like your response lifecycle initiator i mentioned above. Whatever data you call this callback with, is equivalent to your response object you would send in express,you are just abstracted,to what you really do in an express route, and so the callback gets called.

```
    socket.emit('test', 'This is a message', (xxx) => {
    /// xxx has data from server if any
    console.log('Callback Function');
    });
```

This is actually what socket io is referring as the acknowledgement.
Go through the [docs, acknowledgement](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emitting-events/#acknowledgements) section once more and keenly